# I can't add Microsoft WebBrowser ActiveX Control on Excel 2013 worksheet

Tags: excel, controls, activex, worksheet

I can't add Microsoft WebBrowser ActiveX Control on Excel 2013 worksheet, please help. It show "Cannot insert object" message when I drag icon into worksheet. How should I do ?